# RegionIntersection fails for some values with polygons

Tags: bugs, polygons

**Bug introduced in 10.1 and fixed in 10.3.0**

---

I want to find the intersection (region) of 2 polygons. I use `RegionInstersection` but it only works for some sizes, for example, when `c=.5` it gives the correct result, but with `c=.4` it only finds a line as intersection.

`Area[r3[.5]]` works fine...

`Area[r3[.4]]` does not work...

What is wrong?

```
b = 15.0;
d = 4.0;
lbp = 40.0;
d1E = 2.;
l1E = 7.0;
d1D = d1E;
l1D = 5.0;

r1 = Polygon[{{0, 0}, {lbp/2 - l1D, 0}, {lbp/2, d1D}, {lbp/2, 
     d}, {-(lbp/2), d}, {-(lbp/2), d1E}, {-(lbp/2) + l1E, 0}}];
r2[c_] := Rectangle[{-1.1 lbp/2, -1.5}, {1.1 lbp/2, c}];
r3[c_] := RegionIntersection[r1, r2[c]];
```

Comment: This is a bug. For a workaround, use exact numbers everywhere or discretize `r1` and `r2[c]` first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This bug has been fixed as of *Mathematica* 10.3.

```
b = 15.0; d = 4.0; lbp = 40.0; d1E = 2.; l1E = 7.0; d1D = d1E; l1D = 5.0;
r1 = Polygon[{{0, 0}, {lbp/2 - l1D, 0}, {lbp/2, d1D}, {lbp/2, d}, 
              {-(lbp/2), d}, {-(lbp/2), d1E}, {-(lbp/2) + l1E, 0}}];
r2[c_] := Rectangle[{-1.1 lbp/2, -1.5}, {1.1 lbp/2, c}];
r3[c_] := RegionIntersection[r1, r2[c]];
{Area[r3[.5]], Area[r3[.4]]}

(* {14.75, 11.68} *)
```