# RegionIntersection of a scaled cone? (elliptical cone)

Tags: regions, intersection

I can generate the intersection of a line and a cone (from the example in the documentation). Is there a simple way to do the same for a line and an elliptical cone?

i.e., this works:

```
r1 = InfiniteLine[{{-1, -2, -3}, {1, 2, 3}}];
r2 = Cone[{{0, 0, 2.}, {0, 0, -4}}, 1];
r3 = RegionIntersection[r1,r2]
```

Line[{{-0.243659, -0.487317, -0.730976}, {0.38401, 0.768019, 
   1.15203}}]

```
Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.5], {Red, r1}, {Green, r2}, {Blue, r3}}]
```

[image]

And I can make an elliptical cone using scale:

```
r4 = Scale[Cone[{{0, 0, 2.}, {0, 0, -4}}, 1], {2, 4, 3}, {0, 0, 0}];
```

[image: Elliptical cone]

But r4 has head "Scale" rather than a Region. So RegionIntersection isn't happy:

```
RegionIntersection[r1,r4]
RegionIntersection::reg: Scale[Cone[{{0,0,2.},{0,0,-4}},1],{2,4,3},{0,0,0}] is not a correctly specified region. >>
```

Is there a way to convert r4 to a correctly specified region or does RegionIntersection work for specific shapes only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ScalingTransform` instead of `Scale`:

```
r4 = TransformedRegion[
 Cone[{{0, 0, 2.}, {0, 0, -4}}, 1], 
 ScalingTransform[{2, 4, 3}]
]
```

However, this isn't a `Region` object but a `TransformedRegion`. In my experience, Mathematica's region support is patchy and regularly doesn't work as expected - for instance, the `TransformedRegion` docs themselves are either incomplete or wrong, in the Scope/Derived Regions example, input line 3.

`DiscretizeRegion` fails to discretize `r4` as stated, though it can discretize the intersection with the line, and it manages on `r4` if you use exact `2` instead of `2.` in the definition of the cone. `Graphics3D` fails with all of them. You can still use `RegionMeasure`, `Area`, `Volume` etc with them, though.

This may be related to [this bug](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/87746/regionintersection-fails-for-some-values-with-polygons).

Comment: Great! Thanks Patrick, then I can use :    `dr = DiscretizeRegion[RegionIntersection[r1, r4]]`
and then   `MeshCoordiates[
   dr][[-1]]` and `[[-2]]` appear to be the two end points (although I'm not sure if this will always be the case). Giving :
       `Show[dr, Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.3], {Red, r4}}], 
    Graphics3D[{PointSize[Large], Green, 
      Point[{Last[MeshCoordinates@dr], MeshCoordinates[dr][[-2]]}]}], 
    ImageSize -> 200]`   (I can't figure out the formatting in this comment. Sorry!)